# why does ./regenerate-makefiles.sh gives error to compile irstlm

Tags: moses

I've got a problem compiling irstlm. I've extracted it following the steps from moses and tried another way, but I always get this error:

```
bash: ./regenerate-makefiles.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of IRSTLM later than 5.80.03, make sure you are in the "trunk" folder first.